# Rebooting makes my machine unreachable

Tags: 18.04, reboot

Currently i'm using Ubuntu18.04-LTS-Minimal (From Hetzner), whenever i run the command `reboot` i can not reach to my server untill i ordered a KVM (from Hetzner so they can plug it into my machine) and run `dhclient` or `service ssh restart` why would it happen and how can i fix it?

This started to happen (may be just a coincidence) after i changed my hostname by using Webmin panel, my hostname was `Ubuntu-1804-bionic-64-minimal` and i changed it into `MemeNetwork-i9-9900K`

That's my current Hostname, networking settings;

[image: That's my current Hostname, networking settings]

Comment: I mean it was working just fine, this started to happen (may be just a coincidence) after i changed my hostname by using Webmin panel, my hostname was Ubuntu-18.04-lts-minimal and i changed it into MemeNetwork-i9-9900K

Comment: I just added that info into my question

Comment: What do you mean by "I cannot reach the server"? How are you trying to reach it, by ssh, or by some other means? What do you mean by "order a KVM?" Where do you order a KVM from? Amazon perhaps? Please edit your question and add the new information.

Comment: I mean i can't even ping my servers ip from my windows computer by using cmd, KVM is a console, i order from Hetzner so they plug it into my machine

Comment: I see. Please edit the question with the new explanation. I am not familiar with Helzner.